# Angular 2 Form validations on blur

Tags: angular, forms, validation

i made the following form and relative validation controls:

```
<div class="row page-titles">
  <div class="col-md-5 align-self-center">
    <h3 class="text-themecolor">Agente</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7 align-self-center">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="">Agenti</a>
      </li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="">Aggiungi nuovo agente</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form action="#" #formAggiuntaUser="ngForm" class="form-horizontal" ngNativeValidate>
          <div class="form-body">
            <div class="row m-t-20">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row text-center">
                  <label class="control-label text-right col-md-4">Nome</label>
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome" #nomeField="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="agente.name"
                           required>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="nomeField.errors">
                      <div class="text-left" [hidden]="!nomeField.hasError('required')">
                        Nome è richiesto.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--/span-->
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label text-right col-md-4">Cognome</label>
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cognome" #cognomeField="ngModel"
                           [(ngModel)]="agente.surname" required>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="cognomeField.errors">
                      <div [hidden]="!cognomeField.hasError('required')">
                        Cognome è richiesto.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--/span-->
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label text-right col-md-4">Via</label>
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="indirizzo" #indirizzoField="ngModel"
                           [(ngModel)]="agente.indirizzo" required>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="indirizzoField.errors">
                      <div [hidden]="!indirizzoField.hasError('required')">
                        Indirizzo è richiesto.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--/span-->
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label text-right col-md-4">Numero civico</label>
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="civico" #civicoField="ngModel"
                           [(ngModel)]="agente.civico" required>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="civicoField.errors">
                      <div [hidden]="!civicoField.hasError('required')">
                        Numero civico è richiesto.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--/span-->
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label text-right col-md-4">Città</label>
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="città" #cittaField="ngModel"
                           [(ngModel)]="agente.citta" required>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="cittaField.errors">
                      <div [hidden]="!cittaField.hasError('required')">
                        Città è richiesta.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--/span-->
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label text-right col-md-4">Provincia</label>
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="provincia" #provinciaField="ngModel"
                           [(ngModel)]="agente.provincia" required>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="provinciaField.errors">
                      <div [hidden]="!provinciaField.hasError('required')">
                        Provincia è richiesta.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--/span-->
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label text-right col-md-4">Email</label>
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="agente.email"
                           #emailField="ngModel"
                           pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" email required>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="emailField.errors">
                      <div [hidden]="!emailField.hasError('required')">
                        Email è richiesta.
                      </div>
                      <div [hidden]="!emailField.hasError('pattern')">
                        Inserire una email valida.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--/span-->
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label text-right col-md-4">Numero di telefono</label>
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input class="form-control"
                           type="tel" name="telefono" #telefono="ngModel"
                           pattern="[0-9]*"
                           #telField="ngModel"
                           [(ngModel)]="agente.telefono" required>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="telField.errors">
                      <div [hidden]="!telField.hasError('required')">
                        Numero di telefono è richiesto.
                      </div>
                      <div [hidden]="!telField.hasError('pattern')">
                        Inserire un numero di telefono corretto.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label text-right col-md-4">Password</label>
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" #passField="ngModel"
                           [(ngModel)]="agente.password" required>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="passField.errors">
                      <div [hidden]="!passField.hasError('required')">
                        Password è richiesta.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--/span-->
            </div>
            <!--/row-->
            <!--/row-->
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="form-actions">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-9">

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!formAggiuntaUser.form.valid" (click)="addUser()" class="btn btn-info"><i
                      class="fa fa-plus"></i> Aggiungi agente
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But i have a really great problem: all required error immediately appears in the beginning, while i want to display required error only when the user blur on the input.
I really don't know how could i initially reset the errors...
Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the input is pristine or valid when it is time to hide the error message. It means that the input has been touched or changed.
For exemple:

```
<div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
     class="alert alert-danger">
```

In your case that would be:

```
<div [hidden]="!civicoField.hasError('required') || civicoField.pristine ">
                    Numero civico è richiesto.
                  </div>
```

cf: https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: Thanks man, simple and efficient! I have another problem: angular automatically add ng invalidate because of required... do you know if there is a way to initially set required (something like pristine)? Because inputs are red at the start

Comment: You can try to manually set the ng-invalid class, something like `<input [class.ng-invalid]="!civicoField.hasError('required') || civicoField.pristine ">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form [ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: blur}">
  ... 
</form>
```

It was introduced in Angular 5.0. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/0d45828)

Comment: Exactly, i was looking for it but did'nt remember the name. I was sure it has been introduced recently. Nice.

Comment: Glad I could help. Can you mark my answer as the solution?

Comment: I am not the one who asked the question :D

Comment: I added ngFormOptions but errors continue to appears.